# HBase connector does not read ZK configuration from Spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to write a Spark program that reads data from HBase and store it in DataFrame.

I am able to run it perfectly with `hbase-site.xml` in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf` folder, but I am facing few issues here.

#### Issue 1

The first issue is passing `hbase-site.xml` location with the `--files` parameter submitted through `client` mode (it works in `cluster` mode).

When I  removed `hbase-site.xml` from `$SPARK_HOME/conf` and tried to execute it in `client` mode by passing with the `--files` parameter over YARN I keep getting the an exception (which I think means it is not taking the ZooKeeper configuration from `hbase-site.xml`.

```
spark-submit \
  --master yarn \
  --deploy-mode client \
  --files /home/siddesh/hbase-site.xml \
  --class com.orzota.rs.json.HbaseConnector \
  --packages com.hortonworks:shc:1.0.0-2.0-s_2.11 \
  --repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/ \
  target/scala-2.11/test-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

---

```
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1125)
18/02/22 01:43:09 INFO ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
18/02/22 01:43:09 WARN ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1125)
```

However it works good when I run it in `cluster` mode.

#### Issue 2

Passing the HBase configuration details through the Spark session, which I can't get to work in both `client` and `cluster` mode.

Instead of passing the entire `hbase-site.xml` I am trying to add the configuration directly in the code by adding it as a configuration parameter in the `SparkSession`, e.g.:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(name)
  .config("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
  .config("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "ip1,ip2,ip3")
  .config("spark.hbase.host","zookeeperquorum")
  .getOrCreate()

val json_df =
  spark.read.option("catalog",catalog_read).
  format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").
  load()
```

This is not working in `cluster` mode either.

---

Can anyone help me with a solution or explanation why this is happening are there any workarounds?